# Cannot run huge Python program

Tags: python, pycharm, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run a python program using Pycharm IDE but unable to do so without stumbling into "Your system has run out of application memory". After some research I came across a suggestion of using Microsoft Azure ML. Can anyone point me to some helpful links that can get me started or any other suggestions at all?

Edit: I am working with a data that has 400,000 samples and ~5000 samples and I want to use chi2 feature selection but I am unable to run the program.

Comment: I hope I have given enough information to put this question back on track. I haven't had much of progress with this question so I don't have any code to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: PyPy to run your program with less memory usage and more speed. see this [pypy site](http://pypy.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately installing PyPy is raising a lot of errors which I cannot overcome.  Any other suggestion would be greatly appreciated!